# Angular 2 + ASP.Net MVC template in visual studio

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to incorporate angular 2 with MVC 5 template in visual studio 2015. When I use angular 2 + MVC 5 template in visual studio, I am getting typescript errors like "`toPromise`", "`map`" does not exists on type of `Observable<Response>`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have   "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6" installed and then import:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

into your service.  This will provide those operators for you.

Comment: I would add it to @NgModules to prevent import duplications

Comment: I imported those files. I am able to build the solution. Thank you. And one more thing, the UI is getting loaded before calling the web api. Because of that data in UI is undefined. Could you please help me on this.

Comment: sorry, don't know enough about MVC to help. If you like the previous answer please mark it.